# How can I return value from execute of Executor - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

How can I return value from `execute` of `Executor`:

```
fun MyFunc(): Int {
private val executor: Executor =
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
  executor.execute { appRepository.tblCoursesIsEmptyAppRepo() }
}
```

I used from `postValue` but it get me old value always.

Answer (score 1):

Use kotlin Coroutines it's very rich and concise than Executor and you can get a value of livedata by postValue() method.

To use coroutine add gradle files:

```
def coroutines_version = "1.3.3"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
```

and use below code:

```
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        exception.printStackTrace()
    }

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(handler) {
        resultLiveData.postValue(appRepository.tblCoursesIsEmptyAppRepo())
    }
```

Comment: It's not third party library it is a kotlin official library. Google it to know more about.

Comment: @ Md. Yamin. How can I return value with you source code?

Comment: @PEDY Let me know are you making a network call or getting data from database?

Comment: @ Md. Yamin. Your source good work but how return value with this?

Comment: @PEDY See I edited the answer that is using a LiveData and it's postValue() method to save data returned by your repo into the LiveData variable. If you still can not understand then please declare a MutableLiveData variable of your desired type then use the postValue() method to return data into that variable and you can observe that live data to be notified when a new data is returned into that livedata variable.

Comment: No, I used from postValue and it is not good it get me old value always.

Comment: Let me know are you making network call or getting data from database?

Answer (score 0):

I used from bellow source code and it good work:

```
    val callable = Callable { appRepository.tblCoursesIsEmptyAppRepo() }

    val future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(callable)

    Log.i(TAG, future.get())
```